# Are correct this git rebase steps two git branches?

Tags: git, branch, rebase

Firstly, I've created a new branch from my master called `D` and I did a pull from another branch `C`.

I did some changes and end it, later I did a `git fetch` (to bring the possible changes from master).

I wanted to have my changes with the `master` changes in one branch so I did a rebase.

I did it and there were conflicts, but I didn't understand because if I create my branch (`D`) from my master, should I have already that changes, right ?

I've resolved all the conflicts (`git add` and `git rebase --continue`) but when I've tried to push to my repository I got this error:

```
! [rejected]        project-4.x.x -> project-4.x.x (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.cee.xxx.myrepo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Then I did a pull again and now I have to resolve a lot of conflicts before try to push again.
Is it correct? or I am missing anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After running a `rebase` on one of your branch, it is expected that your local history will not match the remote history anymore.

In this particular situation, you should not try to pull the remote, you should force push your branch back to the remote :

```
git push --force origin D
```

If you currently have an ongoing merge with conflicts because of your `git pull`, just abort it :

```
git merge --abort
```

---

Some explanations :

Before the rebase, the situation you describe must have looked like this :

```
*--*--*--a--b--c < D, origin/D           # you did some work on branch D
       \
        *--*--m < master, origin/master  # master received some more commits
```

Then you rebased your work on `master` :

```
*--*--*--a--b--c < origin/D
       \
        *--*--m--a'--b'--c' < D   # 'git rebase' created new commits on top of master
              ^
              master, origin/master
```

In this situation : your local `D` branch is no longer a "fast forward" extension of `origin/D`, you have to use `git push --force origin D` to tell the git server "this is the history I actually want"